# How to write a comparator for map and priority_queue where the elements are 2 dimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, comparator, priority-queue

I am trying to implement A* search for a N puzzle whose size is 15. My start state   would be random. The goal state is the des array in the code. I can only swap   tiles with 0 (blank state) in 4 directions in the puzzle to create a new state.  To implement this I have used a priority_queue and 4 maps. For all of these ,  I have used 2 dimensional array. Compare is the comparator for the priority_queue   and map_cmp is the comparator for the 4 maps. Vis is used to keep track of the visited states, Dis is used to keep count of the path , parent    is used to keep the parent of the state and ab is used to keep the position of 0   (blank space) of each state. Here is the code:

```
enter code here
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define pii pair<int,int>
int fx[]={0,0,1,-1};
int fy[]={1,-1,0,0};
int des[4][4]={{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15}};
int func1(int node[][4])
{
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(i==0 && j==0)
                continue;
            if(des[i][j]!=node[i][j])
                cnt++;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
double func2(int node[][4])
{
    int a,b,x,y;
    double sum=0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(node[i][j]==0)
                continue;
            a=node[i][j];
            x=a/4;
            y=a%4;
            sum+=sqrt((i-x)*(i-x)+ (j-y)*(j-y));
        }
    }
}
struct map_cmp {
    bool operator()(const int (&a)[4][4], const int (&b)[4][4]) const {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                if(a[i][j]!=b[i][j])
                    return true;
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
map<int[4][4],int,map_cmp>vis;
map<int[4][4],int,map_cmp>dist;
map<int[4][4],int[][4],map_cmp>parent;
map< int[4][4],pair<int,int>,map_cmp >ab;
struct compare
{
    bool operator()(const int (&a)[4][4],const int (&b)[4][4] )const{
        return ((dist[a]+func1(a)) < (dist[b]+func1(b)));
    }
};
bool isValid(int row, int col)
{
    return (row >= 0) && (row < 4) && (col >= 0) && (col < 4);
}
int bfs( int src[][4],int a,int b)
 {
    int u[4][4];
    int v[4][4];
    int x,y;
    vis[src]=1;
    dist[src]=0;
    parent[src]={0};
    ab[src]=pii(a,b);
    pii pos;
    priority_queue < int[4][4], vector < int[4][4] > , compare > q;
    q.push(src);
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        u = q.top();
        q.pop();
        pos=ab[u];
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            copy(u,u+16,v);
            x=pos.first+fx[i];
            y=pos.second+fy[i];
            if(isValid(x,y))
            {
                swap(v[pos.first][pos.second],v[x][y]);
                vis[v]=1;
                dist[v]=dist[u]+1;
                ab[v]=pii(x,y);
                parent[v]=u;
                if(memcmp(des,v,sizeof(des))==0)
                    return dist[v];
                q.push(v);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a,b,i,j,k,m,n,x,y;
    int result[5];
    int src[4][4]={{7,2,12,11},{10,14,0,6},{8,13,3,1},{9,5,15,4}};
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(src[i][j]==0)
            {
                x=i;
                y=j;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j!=4)
            break;
    }
    a=bfs(src,x,y);
    ab.clear();
}
```

**The errors i am getting are for the comparator of maps and priority_queue.**
They are:
1. no match for operator[] in dist[a]/vis/parent/ab[in short all the maps]
2. invalid array assignment
3. no matching function for call to 'std::priority_queue, compare>::push(int (*&)[4])'

This is my first post here. Sorry for any mistakes.  Any help will be appreciated as i have already done whatever i can

Comment: C++ doesn't have unsized arrays. The type `int[][4]` is invalid on its own, it's only valid when defining and initializing arrays. As a possible solution, consider using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Then you can use `std::vector<std::array<int, 4>>`.

Comment: I know the array size will be 4*4 . I am modifying my code. Wont it solve the issue u just stated??

Comment: `std::map<std::array<4, std::array<4, int>>, AnyValidType>` compiles, as does `std::priority_queue<std::array<4, std::array<4, int>>>`, because `std::array` has an `operator<` (as does `std::vector`)

Comment: So if i use array<4,int> in map i dont need to write a comparator. right??. I have never used it. So i would like more info. As for priority_queue the comparator which i have written , i just have to change the data type to array<>. Is this ok??

Answer (score 0):

Leave alone the unsized array issue.

Let's consider about the issue in question title, starting from the definition of `std::priority_queue`,
`std::priority_queue<class _Tp, class _Container, class _Compare>`

three parameters are **element type**, **element container**(default std::vector), **comparator**(It's a class with () comparator, default std::less).

```
    class TpType {};

    class TpTypeComparatator {
        bool operator () (TpType &a, TpType &b) const {
            return true;
        }
    };

    std::priority_queue, TpTypeComparatator> q;
```

Comment: I couldn't understand it. My declaration of priority is following the one u just wrote. right??  
     priority_queue < int[4][4], vector < int[4][4] > , compare > q;
    struct compare
    {
        bool operator()(const int (&a)[4][4],const int (&b)[4][4] )const{
            return ((dist[a]+func1(a)) < (dist[b]+func1(b)));
        }
    };

Comment: how about wrapping the two dimension array into a class, or just use it as a int pointer, it'll make it easier for you to understand.

Comment: Ok i get it.  But i was trying to do it this way. Is that not possible?? I will try to do it with the class then. Plz elaborate why is this  giving me error

Comment: `TpTypeComparatator` is not a valid `Compare`, it should instead `return false`